# Omines DataTables does not load data to table on Symfony 4

Tags: jquery, symfony, datatables

I have problem with load data to my table. I tried to use ArrayAdapter from example in documentation https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/ but is also does not load data. I have only title of column. Aby idea ? All ajax request are ok.

Here is action:

```
public function listCalls(Request $request)
{
    $table = $this->createDataTable()
        ->add('id', TextColumn::class, [
            'label' => 'id'
        ])
        ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
            'entity' => Call::class,
            'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
                $builder
                    ->select('c')
                    ->from(Call::class, 'c')
                ;
            },
        ])
        ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($table->isCallback()) {
        return $table->getResponse();
    }

    return $this->render('shop/calls_list.html.twig', [
        'datatable' => $table
    ]);
}
```

And here is view:

```
{% extends "shop/base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}List{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="presidents">Loading...</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/datatables/js/datatables.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#presidents').initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }});
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. The JavaScripts was load in bad order.

Comment: To be more clear you should add at least the right javascript loading order in your answer.